# Displaying all images from a WordPress post

Tags: php, image, wordpress, function

I have this piece of code I found on some blog, that's supposed to display all images from a WordPress post.

```
function getImage() {
    global $more;
    $more = 1;
    $link = get_permalink();
    $content = get_the_content();
    $count = substr_count($content, '<img');
    $start = 0;
    for($i=1;$i<=$count;$i++) {
        $imgBeg = strpos($content, '<img', $start);
        $post = substr($content, $imgBeg);
        $imgEnd = strpos($post, '>');
        $postOutput = substr($post, 0, $imgEnd+1);
        $postOutput = preg_replace('/width="([0-9]*)" height="([0-9]*)"/', '',$postOutput);;
        if(stristr($postOutput,'<img')) { echo $postOutput; }
        $start=$imgEnd+1;
    }
    $more = 0;
}
```

What happens though... it displays first and second image correctly, then loops the second image instead of 3rd 4th etc. It grabs the number of images okay, but instead of displaying 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th image, it displays 1st, 2nd, 2nd, 2nd...

Could anyone look at this snippet and maybe come up with an idea why this happens? I know the code is rather sloppy, but I just found it on some blog, being a PHP newbie and all :)

All help appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$attachments = get_children(array('post_parent' => $post->ID,
                        'post_status' => 'inherit',
                        'post_type' => 'attachment',
                        'post_mime_type' => 'image',
                        'order' => 'ASC',
                        'orderby' => 'menu_order ID'));

foreach($attachments as $att_id => $attachment) {
    $full_img_url = wp_get_attachment_url($attachment->ID);
    // Your Code here
}
```

Also you can have a look here:
http://www.rlmseo.com/blog/get-images-attached-to-post/

Comment: That's very handy, and a more elegant solution I think. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't know what's wrong with that guy's code on rlmseo.com, but it absolutely does not display all images from a post. Even if you add a loop to iterate through $arrKeys as he very vaguely refers to, it doesn't show all the images.

Answer (score 6):

its easier now with the new wordpress **get_attached_media($type,$post)** function

```
$attachments= get_attached_media( 'image', $post->ID );
foreach($attachments as $att_id => $attachment) {
  $full_img_url = wp_get_attachment_url($attachment->ID);
// You can echo it out here
}
```

**note** that this gets only the files **uploaded** to the post . not files added through media library.

Answer (score 2):

Try this ! It may work.

```
function getImage() {
    global $more;
    $more = 1;
    $link = get_permalink();
    $content = get_the_content();
    $count = substr_count($content, '<img');

    for($i=1;$i<=$count;$i++) { 
        //move $start = 0 inside the loop
        $start = 0;
        $imgBeg = strpos($content, '<img', $start);
        $post = substr($content, $imgBeg);
        $imgEnd = strpos($post, '>');
        $postOutput = substr($post, 0, $imgEnd+1);
        $postOutput = preg_replace('/width="([0-9]*)" height="([0-9]*)"/', '',$postOutput);;
        if(stristr($postOutput,'<img')) { echo $postOutput; }
        $content = substr($content,$imgEnd+1);
    }
    $more = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    if ( have_posts() )
    while ( have_posts() ):
    the_post();

    $args = array(
        'post_type'   => 'attachment',
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'post_parent' => $post->ID
        );

    $attachments = get_posts( $args );

    if ( $attachments )
    {
        foreach ( $attachments as $attachment )
        {

        echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, false );

        }
    }

    endwhile;
?>
```

Source : http://960development.com/code-snippet/get-all-the-images-attached-with-a-wordpress-post/

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, you need to add an $imgLength.

```html
function getImage() {
    global $more;
    $more = 1;
    $link = get_permalink();
    $content = get_the_content();
    $count = substr_count($content, '<img');
    $start = 0;
    for($i=1;$i<=$count;$i++) {
        
        $imgBeg = strpos($content, '<img', $start);
        $post = substr($content, $imgBeg);
        $imgLength = strpos($post, '>');
        $imgEnd = $imgBeg + $imgLength;
        $postOutput = substr($post, 0, $imgLength+1);
        $postOutput = preg_replace('/width="([0-9]*)" height="([0-9]*)"/', '',$postOutput);;
        if(stristr($postOutput,'<img')) {    
            echo $postOutput;
        }
        $start=$imgEnd+1;
    }
    $more = 0;
}
```