# I can't get attached images from a post in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

In my local, I can get the attached images from a post with the following code. But in my live server, $images return an empty array. What would be the difference between local and live?

```
$images = get_children(
    array(
        'post_parent' => $post_id,
        'post_status' => 'inherit',
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'post_mime_type' => 'image'
        )
);
```

Thanks

Comment: are you sure the image has post_parrent?

Comment: When I add images to a post, aren't they become automatically the children of that post?

Comment: did you add to text editor(content)? or you add the post_thumbnail?

Comment: I added to the content.

Comment: No, it hasn't post_parent

Comment: Look at the side right, you see set the post thumbnail and set the image for post. That your code is woking now

Comment: What I need is to get the images "in" the post. Featured image is not in my scope.

Comment: You can used to regex to filter image from the content

Comment: If the content has a lot of image, do you get all or the first image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found an answer.. 
I get the images with that code only if I "upload" images directly to that post.

But still curious if there's a way to get images which are inserted to a post (but uploaded before that post).

Comment: Check this out, gets all images from a WP post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081520/displaying-all-images-from-a-wordpress-post

Comment: Thanks but, doesn't the answer offer the same code I'm trying to use? get_children with same parameters. I also tried get_post with attachment.