# Wordpress - Print array of img url's into respective tags

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach, domdocument

I'm trying to show images contained within `the_content()` in a specific way. I've already managed to extract the images url path with `DOMDocument()` as follows:

```
<?php
$content = get_the_content();
$dom = new DOMDocument;
 if ($dom->loadHTML($content)) {
  $imgs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
   if ($imgs->length > 0) {
    foreach ($imgs as $img) {
     $img->getAttribute('src');
    }
   }
 }
?>
```

Echoing the `$img` array shows that the code above is working correctly. What I need now is to loop through the array and print each array element into a `<img>` tag `src` field. The following prints blank links:

```
<?php foreach ($imgs as $img) { ?>
                    <a class="fancybox" rel="galeria1" href="<?php echo htmlentities($img); ?>" title="teste">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo htmlentities($img); ?>" alt="" width="474" height="315"></a>
                    <?php } ?>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I'd do it that way, it's quite a messy implementation IMO, but to answer your question:

To display the image you need to grab what value is inside the actual image:

```
$img
```

Like so:

```
$img->getAttribute('src')
```

It looks like you've done this in your first example but not your second ?

Your second example should look like this:

```
<?php foreach ($imgs as $img) { ?>
    <a class="fancybox" rel="galeria1" href="<?php echo $img->getAttribute('src'); ?>" title="teste">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $img->getAttribute('src');  ?>" alt="" width="474" height="315"></a>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Oh, I see my mistake now. It works, thanks. About it being messy, I do agree but that's the only way I've found to have absolute control over the images inside the_content(). Do you have any advice on this matter?

Comment: There won't be an easy way to do so and if you're using this code in your template I think it's a quick win. But otherwise have a look here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081520/displaying-all-images-from-a-wordpress-post). You can query a post_content for all the attachments, then you could potentially create a filter on the_content to do what you need with the images.

Comment: Nice, will take a look. Thank you very much!