# Get all attachments from current page in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I try to get all attachments from a current wordpress page. But my code only shows me the first result. What´s the issue?

**My code**

```
<?php
$attachments = get_children(array(
  'post_parent' => $post->ID,
    'post_status' => 'any',
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image'
)
);

foreach($attachments as $att_id => $attachment) {
  if (get_post_meta( $attachment->ID, '_bildnachweis', true )) {
      $full_img_caption = get_post_meta( $attachment->ID, '_bildnachweis', true );
      echo $full_img_caption; // Here I need more results, but the browser shows me only one.
  }
}
?>
```

`echo $full_img_caption;` shows me only one result instead of three existing images for the page. There is a problem with my `foreach` loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way that works:

```
<?php
//This will return the HTML source of the page as a string.
$htmlString = $post->post_content;

//Create a new DOMDocument object.
$htmlDom = new DOMDocument;

//Load the HTML string into our DOMDocument object.
@$htmlDom->loadHTML($htmlString);

//Extract all img elements / tags from the HTML.
$imageTags = $htmlDom->getElementsByTagName('img');

//Create an array to add extracted images to.
$extractedImages = array();

//Loop through the image tags that DOMDocument found.
foreach($imageTags as $imageTag){

    //Get the alt text of the image.
    $classText = $imageTag->getAttribute('class');


    //Add the image details to our $extractedImages array.
    $extractedImages[] = array(
        'class' => $classText
    );
}

?>
<div id="image-copyright" class="container">
  <strong>Bildnachweis:</strong>

    <?php
    foreach($extractedImages as $image) {
        $unsplittedImage = $image["class"];
        $imageID = explode("wp-image-", $unsplittedImage)[1];

        $full_img_caption = get_post_meta( $imageID, '_bildnachweis', true );
        if ($full_img_caption) {
            echo "<span class='single-author'>". $full_img_caption ."</span>";
        }
        ?>

        <?php
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `false` instead of `true` in this line: `get_post_meta( $attachment->ID, '_bildnachweis', true )` to get *all*  values. `true` will only return the first value. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/

Comment: Thanks. Now I get an array. But in the array there exists only the value from one image.... but I have three image in the current page..

Comment: hmm - maybe use `$att_id` instead of `$attachment->ID` in the foreach loop

Comment: The same result... maybe because some images are images that I´ve uploaded before from another post? Maybe there are no real children from post ID? But how could get with another method all images from this page?

Comment: There's an accepted answer here which might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4081609/5641669

Comment: I worked with this example, but this not solves the problem :/